# How to execute a Replace only if the cell is not a formula?

Tags: excel, vba, replace, excel-formula

I want to do a mass replacement in a folder with a lot of excel files. Some files are in sub folders. But I want to replace only if the cell I'm replacing in is not a formula. I think I could do that by checking if there is an "=" as the first char of the cell, but I don't know how to code it. So far I have this:

```
Dim FileSystem As Object
Dim HostFolder As String

Sub Init()

HostFolder = "C:\Users\Felipe\Desktop\ReplaceTest\"

Set FileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
DoFolder FileSystem.GetFolder(HostFolder)

End Sub

Sub DoFolder(Folder)
    Dim SubFolder

    For Each SubFolder In Folder.SubFolders
        DoFolder SubFolder
    Next

    Dim File

    For Each File In Folder.Files
        With Workbooks.Open(File)
            Dim worksheet As worksheet

            For Each worksheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
                'I don't want the line below to replace formulas
                ws.Cells.Replace What:="testA", Replacement:="testB", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder _
                    :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
            Next worksheet

        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

It works as is, but it will replace formulas, witch I don't want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Restrict the *Replace* to constants only:

```
ws.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Replace What:="testA", Replacement:="testB", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder _
                    :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
```

**EDIT#1:**

To avoid the annoying error put:

```
On Error Resume Next
```

before the `Replace` and put:

```
On Error Goto 0
```

after the `Replace`

Comment: I did some testing. It works fine, unless it finds a worksheet that is completely empty. It gives me an error saying "No cells were found" and then stops. I don't understand why it must have at least one cell with a value in a worksheet. How do I solve this?

Comment: @FelipeMüller  See my **EDIT#1**